# Logout Facebook session and launch login Activity

Tags: android, facebook, session

I'm using a Facebook button for login in a project. This button is located in LoginActivity, once I log in, it does things right and launch me to the expected Activity.

The problem is in that activity because I have another Facebook button to log out the session. I want that once that I log out the application takes me again to Login Activity. But it does nothing, it just changes the button status.

This is the code of the activity with the button that must take me again to Login Activity.

```
public class Main_Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    LoginButton mFacebookButton;
    CallbackManager mCallBackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_principal);

        mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mFacebookButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_menu_button);

        mFacebookButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                goLoginActivity();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void goLoginActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Main_Menu.this, LoginActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        finish();
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

What can I do in order to launch the login Activity?
Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why u create the Facebook default button again simply take the button and logout from it
//Check if user is currently logged in

```
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null && com.facebook.Profile.getCurrentProfile() != null){
        //Logged in so show the login button
        fb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                gotoLogin();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I thought that it was possible to log out with the Facebook button, but it worked as you said! Thank you so much!